# Trisecting an an angle - how to prove?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have this question on my "History of Mathematics" problem set:

> Draw any angle $\angle AOB$; Pick a point $C$ on $OB$; Now trace $CD$ which is perpendicular to $OA$; Draw a parallel line $s$ to $OA$ which passes through $C$; Now trace the segment $OQ$, with $Q$ in $s$, which intersects $CD$ at $P$ in a way that $PQ = 2OC$.

Prove $\angle AOQ$ is a third of $\angle AOB$.

I have mande the draw, but I have no idea how to get through the proof

Any help is quite welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up "Neusis" and the proof of trisecting an angle. It is impossible by compass and straight-edge construction.

Comment: One can do an angle trisection using compass and straight edge by performing successive bisections (using a handy geometric series where its sum is 1/3) Of course this is a little cheating, because one would need an infinite amount of time to do these bisections....

Comment: I have looked up Neusis, but couldn't provide the proof. I don't really need to make the construction, obviously since it's impossible, just providing the proof.

Comment: I think you mean AOQ is a third of AOB.

Comment: @Ed_4434: I don't see a problem here, since that means that $Q$ can't be constructed with the compass and a straight-edge.

Comment: Yeah, had a typo there, thanks!

Comment: The problem doesn't ask you to do any of this with straightedge or ruler. That it is impossible to construct and find Q isn't relevent.  Such a Q does exist even if it's impossible to construct.  The problem *isn't* a construction problem.

Comment: Given that this came from a "History of Mathematics" problem set, I wonder whether straight edge and ruler construction problems are indeed relevant, with this problem perhaps playing the role of a failed attempt at a such a construction preceding the 19th century proof of impossibility.@fleablood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $b = m(AOB)$ and $a = m(POC)$. Then

$\frac{OC}{\sin OPC} = \frac{PC}{\sin{POC}} = \frac{PQ\sin{PQC}}{\sin{POC}}$

Write the angles in terms of $a$ and $b$ and you'll see why $a = \frac{2}{3}b$, hence $AOQ$ is a third of $AOB$.

Comment: I'm so sorry for being a noobie for this thing, but what is $m(AOB)$? I get that you are using the "Sine Law" and so on, but couldn't figure out what $m$ is. Thank you so much anyway!

Comment: The measure of the angle; I probably should have used $m(AOQ) = \frac{1}{3} m(AOB)$.

Comment: Perfect, done! Thanks a lot!!!